# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present - i don't know how to solve it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing

Every time i want to run my tests coded with spring boot, the same error always occurs. It's java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present and i don't know what to do to resolve it so if u could help me i would really appreciate it.

One of my test class is:

```
package com.project.test.service;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyLong;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;


import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import com.project.entity.Game;
import com.project.entity.GameRepository;

@SpringBootTest
class GameServiceTest {

@Mock
private GameRepository gameRepository;

private Game game;

@Autowired
protected GameService gameService;


@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.setId(4L);
    game.setName("Game1");
}

@Test
void testGetAllGames() throws Exception {
    Set<Game> games= new HashSet<Game>();
    games.add(game);
    when(gameRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(games);
    
    gameService.getAllGames();
    verify(gameRepository).findAll();
    assertEquals(games, gameService.getAllGames());
}


@Test
void getGameById() throws Exception {
    Set<Game> games = new HashSet<Game>();
    games.add(game);
    when(gameRepository.findById(anyLong()).get()).thenReturn(game);
    gameService.getGameById(anyLong());
    verify(gameRepository).findById(anyLong());
    assertEquals(games, gameService.getGameById(anyLong()));
}

}
```

The complete stack trace is:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:141)
    at com.project.test.service.GameServiceTest.getGameById(GameServiceTest.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Also when i click on the trace, it points me to this line of the code:
`gameService.getGameById(anyLong());`

I don't know how to solve the problem since in another project I made them in the same way and had no problem. Thank u for helping me :)

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the complete stack trace; also indicate the statement in your code that caused the exception.

Comment: done, thank u for telling me! @JimGarrison

Comment: `(gameRepository.findById(anyLong())` returned an empty `Optional<>`. In other words, your `GameRepository` class did not find the requested game, and your code did not allow for that possibility.

Comment: oh thank you!! is there any way i could add something to my code so if it doesn't find the requested game, it will not fail? @JimGarrison

Comment: Only you can decide how you you want to handle that condition in your test.  There should be a testcase for that condition.  I haven't used Mockito... does your mocked  `GameRepository` return a value for `findById()`? What does `anyLong()` return?  We can't really tell you how to write your program logic.

Comment: The NoSuchElementException exception is because the Optional object has no "default" value to return when you called the get method on it. You can chain it with .orElse() or .orElseGet() if you want to return another value which can be expected as the value when you didn't find your game so it didn't throw the default exception when it didn't find the game.

Answer (score 0):

Here your code gameService.getGameById(anyLong()) is returning a null value so you will have to put a condition if the value does not exist.

Optional instance, to find out if that particular id exists or not for the game. If id is present, getGameById(anyLong()) will wrap its value, otherwise, it  will wrap a null value. Then, you can use Optional‘s isPresent(), get(), or orElse() methods to work with the value.

```
Optional<Integer> gameId;
if (gameId.isPresent()) {
        Integer gameId = gameId.get();
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
```